# Pin a function pointer

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cli

I need to pass a managed callback to an unmanaged TCP receiver. Since its a thread that needs to exist for the lifetime of the application, I need to prevent it from getting garbage collected. I have read everywhere that pinning function pointers is not required and the GCHandle.Alloc will do the job of preventing garbage collection.

But is this a given? I have seen that the AppPool hosting this code crashes with an access violation. Why should I not suspect the fact that this error occurs because the function pointer was garbage collected?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366436/382795) supports this fact.

Update:
This seems to have reduced the crashes considerably. Is there a problem with this approach?

```
typedef void (__cdecl *ProcMessageFunc)(void* param, void* paramBuf, ULONG bufSize);
FuncDelegate^ fp = gcnew MessageFuncDelegate(this, &Handler); 
pin_ptr<MessageFuncDelegate^> pinnedFunctionPointer = &fp; 
ret = Receiver ((ProcMessageFunc)pinnedFunctionPointer);
```

Comment: Storing the delegate object in a static variable is sufficient.  Native code can bomb with access violations for plenty of other reasons.

Comment: I have done exactly that. The reason why I'm tending towards suspecting garbage collection to be the cause is that the access violation occurs erratically. And more importantly the call stack in the crash dump I can see the native dll followed by the clr.dll and then kernel32.dll at the top of the stack. This order is consistent.

Answer (score 10):

I do exactly what you suggest to do - GCHandle.Alloc on the delegate but with no pinning - and have not had any problems in extensive use on many different platforms and on .NET versions 2.0 - 4. Something like:

```
 DelegateHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(xlDelegate);
 FunctionPointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(xlDelegate);
```

with `FunctionPointer` then passed to the native code, and `DelegateHandle` kept for later cleanup.

This seems to be the best reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0(v=vs.80).aspx.

Nothing in the post you point to contradicts this reference - you do need to protect the delegate from garbage collection, it's just that *pinning is not required*.

Comment: Is address-pinning for functions not necessary because unlike heap objects they exist in a const location? What address does a function have if it hasn't been JIT'd yet btw?

Comment: I think the call to GetFunctionPointerForDelegate builds a little marshaling stub that has a fixed entry point, but if the delegate is moved the stub will still know how to call it. So the exported function pointer is not a direct export of the address of the delegate object (unlike a pinned array or struct member would be). Remember the exported 'native' function must also implement the native -> managed transition.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. Unfortunately the access violation still occurs. Let me put it this way. How can I be perfectly sure that this is NOT the cause for the access violation?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect the delegate (on which you have called GCHandle.Alloc) being collected as the cause of your error? You could check for the GC case by calling GC.Collect() making the collection more deterministic. Most likely the native code is trashing some memory. Is the crash when calling the delegate? Are the parameters OK? Does the delegate call back to native code that might be crashing? All I can share is my experience of it working fine without pinning, as the documentation suggests it should.

Comment: @Govert The delegate is definitely called multiple times. It fails randomly. As mentioned in my comment to the question above, the reason I suspect GC is because the call stack in the crash dump indicates so.

Comment: @Krishter I realize it has been some time, but, can you provide the call stack or is this now a dead-end Q&A?