# C# delegate for C++ callback

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, callback, dllimport

I think I have basically understood how to write c# delegates for callbacks, but this one is confusing me.
The c++ definition is as follows:

```
typedef int (__stdcall* Callback)(
long lCode,
long lParamSize,
void* pParam 
);
```

and my c# approach would be:

```
 unsafe delegate int CallbackDelegate (int lCode, int lParamSize, IntPtr pParam);
```

Although this seems to be incorrect, because I get a PInvokeStackInbalance error, which means my definition of the delegate is wrong.

The rest of the parameters of the function are strings or ints, which means they cannot cause the error, and if I just pass a IntPtr.Zero instead of the delegate (which would mean I'm pointing to a non-existent callback function) I get an AccessViolation error, which makes sense aswell.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The full c++ function is:

```
int
__stdcall
_Initialize (
const char*         FileName,
Callback            cbFunction,
int                 Code,
const char*         Name,
unsigned int        Option,
unsigned int        Option2
);
```

My c# version is:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int _Initialize (string FileName, CallbackDelegate cbFunction, int Code, string Name, uint Options, uint Options2);
```

The function is (for testing) just called inside of the main routine of a console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CallbackDelegate del = new CallbackDelegate(onCallback);

    Console.Write(_Initialize("SomeFile.dat", del, 1000, "", 0, 4));
    Console.Read();
}
```

where `onCallback` is this:

```
static int onCallback(int lCode, int lParamSize, IntPtr pParam)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get the `PInvokeStackInbalance` error on the line where I call `_Initialize`, if I pass a `IntPtr.Zero` instead of the delegate, and change the definition of the function to `IntPtr` instead of `CallbackDelegate` then I get a `AccessViolationException`.

Comment: `The rest of the parameters of the function are strings or ints`.  Don't hide information.

Comment: Have you tried not using unsafe?  i.e: delegate int CallbackDelegate(int lCode, int lParamSize, IntPtr pParam);

Comment: @HansPassant I am not trying to hide information, I was trying to leave away things I considered not relevant. I'll edit the question and add the information.

Comment: @DougEC Just tried that now, doesn't seem to help either

Comment: Edit your question with the your code changed to reflect the suggestions given to you. IntPtr instead of void* and ints rather than longs. Also include the way you call the function and at what point you get the exception. Are you on a 32 bits or 64 bits system?

Comment: @SebastianCabot Done. Running on a 64bit OS. Gonna try on a 32bit OS asap.

Comment: @SebastianCabot The target platform in the project is set to x86 though. If I change it to x64 then I get an error because the dll file is not available in 64bit.

Comment: There can be a lot of problems when running 32bit code on 64bit machine. You should certainly try on a 32 bit machine. Also - are you sure about the calling conventions?

Comment: @SebastianCabot After trying it on a 32bit system, and seeing it work I tried it again on the 64bit system, without debugging it (just running the executable created in the debug folder) and this seems to work...

Answer (score 5):

I added your code to my current project where I'm doing a lot of C#/C++ interop in VS2012. And while I hate to use the "it worked on my machine", it worked fine for me. The code as I ran it is listed out below just to illustrate that I didn't make and fundamental changes.

My suggestion is that you build a new native dll with a stub function for _Initialize such as below and see if it works when you can control both sides of the interface. If that works but the real dll doesn't, it comes down to either compiler settings on the native side or their is a bug on the native side and it is stomping on the stack.

```
extern "C" {

    typedef int (__stdcall* Callback)(long lCode,long lParamSize,void* pParam );

    TRADITIONALDLL_API int __stdcall _Initialize (const char* FileName,Callback cbFunction, int                 Code,
                                const char*         Name,unsigned int        Option,unsigned int        Option2)
    {
        cbFunction(0, 0, nullptr);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

On the C# side, I added the declarations to my interface class:

```
 public delegate int CallbackDelegate(int lCode, int lParamSize, IntPtr pParam);

 [DllImport("XXX.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 public static extern int _Initialize(string FileName, CallbackDelegate cbFunction, int Code, string Name, uint Options, uint Options2);
```

And then in my main:

```
private int onCallback(int lCode, int lParamSize, IntPtr pParam)
{
       return 0;
}
XXXInterface.CallbackDelegate del = new XXXInterface.CallbackDelegate(onCallback);

Console.Write(XXXInterface._Initialize("SomeFile.dat", del, 1000, "", 0, 4));
```

Comment: Thank you for checking this out, should have done that myself. I tried it aswell, and it seems to work.
What have also found out is that the application seems to work if I just start the exe file, WITHOUT the debugger...

Comment: That is odd. It sounds like there is a good chance that there is a bug in the C++ side dll that is affecting the stack. Is there any way for you to get the source for the native dll so that you can run them combined under the debugger? I don't know any other good way to approach it and there is almost certainly no way to FIX it with the source.

Comment: No, sadly I cannot get my hands on the source code, otherwise I think this would be a lot easier. I tried calling the c++ function from a c++ program, and this seems to work perfectly fine. Therefor I think the dll is alright, and I'm just making a mistake with the callback function. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

A .NET `long` is 64bits. A C++ `long` may be just 32bits. Check with the C++ compiler which compiled that definition as to what size it's `long`s are.

Comment: Good input, sadly this doesn't seem to solve the problem. I can't check the C++ compiler, as i just have the .dll and the .h file, but changing the long to Int32 doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
unsafe delegate int CallbackDelegate (int lCode, int lParamSize, IntPtr pParam);
```

If .NET assumes cdecl instead of stdcall, your stack will most assuredly be hosed.